# Send UITableView row From One tableviewController to another

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to send a `UITableViewCell` at `indexPath.row` from one controller to another. I can remove the row using `removeObjectAtIndex`, but unable to send the removed row into another controller.

I'm trying to store the removed row in an `NSMutableArray` in one controller, but don't know how to populate it in another controller.

Below is the code -

```
ViewController *view= [self.storyboard        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
   view.anotherviewArray= [self.arrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

If anyone can give me an idea, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's bad practice to retain UI elements and pass them around your app. You should instead have some kind of a model containing your data, and pass this model from one view controller to the other. I'd recommend checking out tableview frameworks such as the free Sensible TableView framework, as they do an excellent job of providing such a model for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that it's wrong approach to pass UI object as parameter to another controller. 
As I would do it is create some object that encapsulates data model from this cell and pass this object to another view controller.

```
@interface DataObject : NSObject
@property id field1;
@end
```

UI part of cell can be easily copied in Interface Builder, so I don't see problem in that. Probably it would be great to have cell class that could fill necessary field from the object with data. This class you can use in both view controller that have to show the same cell

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)customizeCellWithDataObject:(DataObject *)dataObject;
@end
```

I hope it makes sense to you

Comment: 100% agree. A UITableView should have nothing in it worthy of passing between objects. All it does is display data. It doesn't even know anything about the data. You should take the data and pass that between controllers instead.

Comment: Isn't self.arrayFromAFNetworking a data object?  It appears to me that this array is the dataSource for the first VC.  cezar or @Monis-manzoor - can you provide insight here?

Comment: @KHansenSF It's an NSMutableArray, not data object.

Comment: @Fogmeister I think i haven't dealt with them before. A bit of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you DO want to set the other data source with only this row, you need to pass it as an array.

```
view.anotherviewArray= [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.arrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But it's hard to tell from the little code that you have provided.  I assume that since you are instantiating the viewController you are also transitioning to it below the provided code.  If you are trying to set the array for a viewController already presented, you need to access that one, not create another, perhaps by having saved a reference to it an ivar within the current viewController or another accessible class.

I would also not name a ViewController `view`, it is confusing to anyone reading the code later on.

Editing for my comment below about traversing the hierarchy.  Here is some code that I used in one iPad project to return the final presented viewController.  This method is in the appDelegate.  It is somewhat specific to my project, where there is only one navigationController.  But you can adapt it to yours.  You would test for a viewController that is of the class of your target view controller.

```
- (UIViewController *)topViewController {
  UIViewController *rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;
  UIViewController *topViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;

  while (topViewController && topViewController.presentedViewController) {
      topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
      if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
          UIViewController *presentedViewController = [(UINavigationController *) topViewController topViewController];
          if (presentedViewController) {
              topViewController = presentedViewController;
          }
      }
  }
  return topViewController;
}
```

The other approach is to set a property to it when it is created and presented.  We don't have enough code to get a good idea of your app as a whole. Where are you creating the ViewController instance that you are displaying? By that I mean where you are calling a segue to it, or pushing it onto a navigationController or call presentViewController. Wherever that is, you need to set a property or ivar to it. Let's say that you use a property in your appDelegate as a very generic case.

In your MyAppDelegate.h file you have

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) ViewController *viewController;
```

Wherever you first create it you set that property

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
```

I now think you are trying to add this to a mutableArray in the other ViewController.  Then replacing your code from the tableViewCell above you would use
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.viewController.mutableDataArray addObject:self.arrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    [appDelegate.viewController.tableView reloadData];

I will say that it is not great practice to use the appDelegate for the property.  But it is a generic answer that would work.  It's best to put it in a class which is common to the viewControllers that you are passing data between.  Perhaps a single parent which holds these two viewControllers?

Comment: I have not used viewController in actual project. It's only for the example. Once i have saved the row in an Array, how should i populate it in another UIViewController with tableView?

Comment: Again that depends on code not seen.   instantiateViewController creates a new viewController each time.  It does not return a reference to one already created or one that you will create by the same call later in your code.  If you need one already created, you need to access one already created you need access to that one through a property set when you created it (easier), or by traversing viewControllers in the hierarchy (harder).  If for a later one, then by setting that value in an array set when it is instantiated

Comment: I had made the mistake of thinking that `[storyboard        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]` returned a reference to an existing viewController.   So if that is your issue, then I hope this helps.  If not, please edit your question and provide more info.

Comment: How do i display the stored row in another UITableViewController? I have anotherViewArray.count set in no. of rows. And cell.textLabel.text = [self.anotherArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] set in cellForRowAtIndexPath.